# Turn one subindex into columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
                 Values
Index1   Index2 
   A        a      1
            b      2
   B        a      2
            b      3
   C        a      0
```

And would like to turn the second index into a number of columns (one for each of its values). Note that not all of the primary index entries have *all* of the second index possibilities.

What I would like is the following:

```
Index   a    b
  A     1    2
  B     2    3
  C     0   NaN
```

Answer (score 6):

Select column `Values` for `Series` and then use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df['Values'].unstack()
```